# How to create a cummulative incidence plot from the R 'crrSC'

Tags: r

I run the following example provided by 'crrSC' package, but found it only returned a list of 8 components, not 14. Does any one know why ?
Also, does anyone know how to create cummulative incidence plot based on the model below?

```
# Simulated clustered data set
data(cdata)
crrc(ftime=cdata[,1],fstatus=cdata[,2],
cov1=cdata[,3], 
cluster=cdata[,4])
```

Thanks in advance.